# js event listener on object (Google Maps)

Tags: google-maps-api-3

The following lines of code document what I'm trying to acchieve. In detail, I'm trying to attach an [`addListener`](http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#event) to a DOM object. Sadly it seems that I can't access it.

```
var dom_obj = document.getElementById( 'dom_obj_id' );

console.log( typeof dom_obj ); // console: object

google.maps.event.addListener( dom_obj, 'click', function() {
    // the following two lines don't appear
    alert( 'Test - called from addListener' );
    console.log( dom_obj );
} );
jQuery( zoom_in ).click(
    function() {
        // works
        alert( 'Test - called via jQuery click function' );
        console.log( dom_obj );
        return false;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searched for hours and found the solution seconds after typing the Q...

Simple as it is: Use [`addDomListener`](http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapsEventListener) instead.